# Why my answer is 0.00.. confuse how to convert int to float struct

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, struct, mean

there's something wrong in these variables.
can someone fix this? my answer keep getting on 0.00

Test case:
we want to find the mean between 3 numbers using struct
input=2,
2 of them are: 3 5 8 and 3 5 7

out put should be:
//*3+5+8=(16)/3=5.33
//*3+5+7=(15)/3=5.00

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct rata{
   float in1;
   float in2;
   float in3;
};

float rata2(in1,in2,in3){
   return (float)((in1+in2+in3)/3);
}

void main(){
   int i,n;
   char hasil[100];
   scanf("%d",&n);
   struct rata walao;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++){
      scanf("%d %d %d",&walao.in1,&walao.in2,&walao.in3);
      hasil[i]=rata2(walao.in1,walao.in2,walao.in3);
   }
   for (i=0;i<n;i++){
      printf("%.2f\n",hasil[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Get a modern compiler and read what it says about the `rata2` function.

Comment: What is the type of the parameters to `rata2`?

Comment: rata = mean.. i used indonesian language

Comment: And is this legal C? My memory and knowledge of C is rather old but this: `22(` ?

Comment: (Enable warnings / errors and read them..)

Comment: yeah i just edited it.. wrong typed.. there's no 22

Comment: there's no error but the program still compiles the answer to 0.00

Comment: 1.Give types to parameters in `rata2`. 2. Fix the incorrect `22((in1+...` syntax. 3. The signature of main is `int main(void)`. 4. When using `scanf` to read a `float` use `%f`, not `%d`. 5. Print `char`s with `%c`, not `%f`.

Comment: i just want to know how to add integer variables then divided it into float tyoe

Comment: can u correct it cause i'm still learning in function parameter?

Comment: https://ideone.com/teW7A6

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11` shouldn't compile any more!

Comment: and please indent your code properly.

Comment: thanks mate .. it's done

Comment: [Check Godbolt for errors](https://godbolt.org/g/bMFmFD)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala which program software did u use? i used code blocks and it runs smoothly

Comment: https://ideone.com/cClPVE#stdin

Comment: that's the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 errors in your code that is preventing you from getting the correct answer. Can you find them? Here's a hint, they have to do with types.

Below are the answers and the reasons behind them.

1. > `char hasil[100]` is assigning hasil to be a char array of size 100. While chars can be assigned numerical values, they are to be treated as integers if they are. Floats =/= Integers, and this should be rectified by saying `float hasil[100]`
2. > `scanf("%d %d %d",&walao.in1,&walao.in2,&walao.in3)` is scanning for 3 **digits**. Since floats can also be assigned integer values, this is valid. However, the language requires that all values used in a calculation should be the same type (hint for 3!). To fix you can do 1 of 2 things, both are legal but entirely up to you. You can either write it as `scanf("%f %f %f",&walao.in1,&walao.in2,&walao.in3)` or keep it as is. Your choice will come to play in final error
3. > The input `rata2` is taking is unspecified. Is it ints? floats? chars? It doesn't know but it trys to resort to using ints, as mostly everything in C can be represented by a number. Since it resorts to ints, the value returned by your calculation is an int as well and no late cast to float will change that. Those variables need to be specified as *something* and how you handled error 2 decides what you do here. If you changed the earlier scanf to take floats instead of digits, rewrite rata as `float rata2(float in1, float in2, float in3)`, remove the cast and you're done. If you kept as is, rewrite rata as `float rata2(int in1, int in2, int in3)`, and rewrite the return as `return ((float)in1 + (float)in2 + (float)in3)/3;`. Either course of action is acceptable but its far more easier and faster specifying them as floats then trying to cast everything (Plus its a LOT cleaner).

This should rectify your code (tested it on my machine). Also, for future note, do

> `scanf("%d",&n);float hasil[n];`

It makes more sense and you don't have to run into the issue of people specifying memory you don't have access to.

Comment: Floats are not treated the same memory wise as ints and chars correct?